# Terminal en un programa Python/Tkinter. El texto desaparece por abajo

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

Estoy haciendo mi primer programa en tkinter y quiero incorporar la terminal de linux, como por ejemplo tiene el editor Atom.
He conseguido incorporarla, pero al ejecutar una orden el texto desaparece dentro del frame y solo se puede ver la línea de comandos haciendo un clear. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la GUI es el siguiente, quedando la terminal incorporada al Frame2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

from conectar import Conecta
from venta import TabVenta
from stock import TabStock
from emailTab import TabEmail
from altaTab import AltaProductos
import os
root = Tk()
class GUI(Frame):
def btn_press(self,event):
    x, y, widget = event.x, event.y, event.widget
    elem = widget.identify(x, y)
    index = widget.index("@%d,%d" % (x, y))
    if "close" in elem:
        widget.state(['pressed'])
        widget.pressed_index = index
def btn_release(self,event):
    x, y, widget = event.x, event.y, event.widget
    if not widget.instate(['pressed']):
        return
    elem =  widget.identify(x, y)
    index = widget.index("@%d,%d" % (x, y))
    if "close" in elem and widget.pressed_index == index:
        widget.forget(index)
        widget.event_generate("<<NotebookClosedTab>>")
    widget.state(["!pressed"])
    widget.pressed_index = None
def __init__(self, master):
    master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))
    master.update()
    self.ancho = master.winfo_width()
    self.alto = master.winfo_height()

    def formulario(alto,ancho):
        nuevatab = ttk.Frame(note)
        TabVenta(nuevatab,Frame3,alto,ancho)
        note.add(nuevatab, text = "Formulario venta", compound=TOP)
        note.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    def stock():
        nuevatab = ttk.Frame(note)
        TabStock(nuevatab,Frame3,self.alto,self.ancho)
        note.add(nuevatab, text = "Gestión de Stock", compound=TOP)
        note.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    def email():
        nuevatab = ttk.Frame(note)
        TabEmail(nuevatab,Frame3,self.alto,self.ancho)
        note.add(nuevatab, text = "Envío de emails", compound=TOP)
        note.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    def alta():
        nuevatab = ttk.Frame(note)
        AltaProductos(nuevatab,Frame3,self.alto,self.ancho)
        note.add(nuevatab, text = "Alta de productos", compound=TOP)
        note.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    PhotoImage
    i1 = tkinter.PhotoImage("img_close", file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/close.png")
    i2 = tkinter.PhotoImage("img_closeactive",file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/close.png")
    i3 = tkinter.PhotoImage("img_closepressed",file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/close.png")
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
        ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
        ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')
    style.layout("ButtonNotebook", [("ButtonNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
    style.layout("ButtonNotebook.Tab", [
        ("ButtonNotebook.tab", {"sticky": "nswe", "children":
            [("ButtonNotebook.padding", {"side": "top", "sticky": "nswe",
                                         "children":
                [("ButtonNotebook.focus", {"side": "top", "sticky": "nswe",
                                           "children":
                    [("ButtonNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                     ("ButtonNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''})]
                })]
            })]
        })]
    )
    Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
    # no incluido self.menubar = Menu(self)
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Frame1 = Frame(master, bg="white")
    Frame1.place(x=0,y=0,width=3*self.ancho/4,height=3*self.alto/4)

    #Frame2 = Frame(master, bg="black")
    #Frame2.place(x=0,y=3*self.alto/4,width=3*self.ancho/4,height=self.alto/4)

    Frame2 = Frame(master,padx=10, pady=50)

    Frame2.place(x=0,y=3*self.alto/4,width=3*self.ancho/4,height=self.alto/4)
    wid = Frame2.winfo_id()
    os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 300x10 -sb &' % wid)


    Frame3 = Frame(master, bg="#b3b6bc")
    Frame3.place(x=3*self.ancho/4,y=0,width=self.ancho/4,height=self.alto)
    label = Label(Frame3, text="OUTPUT QUE MUESTRA INFO").pack()
    self.master.bind_class("TNotebook", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.btn_press, True)
    self.master.bind_class("TNotebook", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.btn_release)
    note = ttk.Notebook(Frame1, style="ButtonNotebook")
    note.pressed_index = None

    Frame1.update()
    alto1 = Frame1.winfo_height()
    ancho1 = Frame1.winfo_width()
    formulario(alto1,ancho1)
    #stock()
    email()
    alta()
    datos = Conecta()
    #datos.insertaTipo('bebidas')
    #datos.insertaProducto('BEBIDAS',17283,'CocaCola',1,50)
    #datos.insertaProducto('BEBIDAS',17284,'VollDamm',1,35)
#root.geometry('500x1000+0+0')
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione reduciendo el tamaño del frame, siendo la clave que le resto un octavo del alto de la pantalla a la hora de hacer el place del Frame2 que contiene la terminal.

```
Frame2.place(x=0,y=3*self.alto/4,width=3*self.ancho/4,height=(self.alto/4)-self.alto/8)
wid = Frame2.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 300x10 -sb &' % wid)
```